# Can I create personal bookmarks for pdf-Documents?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

Is there a way to bookmark pages in a PDF document?

For instance, in PDF documentation of a well known commercial database I very often have to navigate my favorite pages. I'd like to bookmark these, so I can reach them with one click. The pre-generated bookmarks in these documents are not useable like personal bookmarks because they are way too many.

An obvious alternative is to just bookmark pages in the corresponding HTML documentation. That would be possible for the well known database's documentation but not every PDF is available in HTML or has a pleasant HTML rendering.

I have looked through the Acrobat Reader menus, SO and googled a bit for no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your pdf-reader.
On linux you could use 'okular' where you even can mark text or add comments in your documents. This information will be stored in a separate file.